# How to go back to a previous part of the code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I am working on a CLI application and using [PyInquirer](https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer) to create a select menu. So what I have created is a select menu, which asks the user to choose what to do, the options are:

> 1. view task,
> 2. Add Task,
> 3. Push up Task.

I've created a function that when you select view task, it prompts another set of choices. However, from here I'd like to return back to the main menu. I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic I need to do this. I know I could hard-code all the possible paths but there must be a better way to do this. I thought about creating functions but the only way I could think of them is by calling each other which wouldn't work.

```
def main():

main_menu_selection = prompt(main_menu, style=custom_style_2)
# Part I reference below
if main_menu_selection['which_task']== 'View Tasks':
    view_tasks_selection = prompt(view_tasks, style=custom_style_2)


if (view_tasks_selection['view_task']).lower() == 'daily':
    print_tasks("daily")
    # Function to return to menu
    print("Press Enter to return to Main Menu")
    user_input = input()
    if user_input:
        main_menu_selection = prompt(main_menu, style=custom_style_2)
        # Here I would need it to go back to the if statement mentioned above
```

Thank you for any guidance or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing in a `while True:` statement, so that whenever you've finished with any of the pathways, you return to the main menu select. When you want to quit, just use `break` to exit out of the loop. Below is a quick example.

```
def main():

    while True:
        main_menu_selection = prompt(main_menu, style=custom_style_2)

        # Part I reference below
        if main_menu_selection['which_task']== 'View Tasks':
            view_tasks_selection = prompt(view_tasks, style=custom_style_2)


        if (view_tasks_selection['view_task']).lower() == 'daily':
            print_tasks("daily")

        else:
            break
```

Comment: The second `main_menu_selection = prompt(main_menu, style=custom_style_2)` should just be `continue`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I couldn't figure out where to put that break statement when I did it. Thanks!